# Place variable in redirect link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to take a variable derived from an HTML form submission, and place it inside of a `window.location.replace` link.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="search.js" type="search">
     <input type="text" name="searchInput" class="textbox" placeholder='' maxlength="10" />    
</form>
```

On form submission, I've assigned searchInput to a JS variable.

Then, I want to place it after the ?query= in the link below:

`https://www.youtube.com/channel/.../search?query=SEARCHINPUT`

Is there a way to do this using JavaScript like below? Or is there a better solution using PHP?

`window.location.replace="https://www.youtube.com/channel/.../search?query=[var=searchinput]`

Comment: Can't you use `window.location.href = window.location.href+"?query="+SEARCHINPUT`   ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, do this:

```
window.location.replace=".../search?query=" + $("[name=searchInput]").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this even just using the default form submit behavior if you change the `action` attribute of your form to the url you want to hit (without the query parameters), then change the name of your input to `query`.

```
<form action="https://www.youtube.com/channel/.../search">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="textbox" placeholder='' maxlength="10" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The default behavior of submitting a form will serialize your form values and place them after a `?` at the end of the url in your `action` attribute.

So if you ran the above code, typed in 'search' in the input box, then clicked submit, your browser would be redirected to `https://www.youtube.com/channel/.../search?query=search`. (Note that this won't work in sanboxed environments such as StackSnippets, jsfiddle, etc., as they won't allow you to redirect to another domain, which is why I didn't make this a StackSnippet)